# Create multi-level JSON with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I can't figure out how to create a multi-level JSON output using PHP and MySQL.

I have this query (simplified for this question)

```
$query = "SELECT 
           1 as id, 
           JSON_OBJECT('key1', 1, 'key2', 'abc') as json1";
```

which I turn into an array

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $resultArray[] = $row;
}
return $resultArray;
```

and then use json_encode:

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

This gets me

```
[
    {
        id: "1",
        json1: "{"key1": 1, "key2": "abc"}"
    }
]
```

i.e., the variable is returned as a string.

What I would like to achieve is to have the variable json_test as a second level of JSON, like so:

```
[
    {
        id: "1",
        json1: 
                  {
                       key1: 1, 
                       key2: "abc"
                  }
    }
]
```

I have tried following hints around this site, but no joy:

```
JSON_ARRAY(GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('key1', 1, 'key2', 'abc'))) AS json2
```

gives me

```
json2: "["{\"key1\": 1, \"key2\": \"abc\"}"]",
```

and

```
CAST(CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('key1', 1, 'key2', 'abc')),']') AS JSON) AS json3
```

gives me

```
json3: "[{"key1": 1, "key2": "abc"}]"
```

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

I'm on PHP 7.0.25 and MySQL 5.7.20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JSON_OBJECT` is returned to PHP as a string (as [prodigitalson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215966/prodigitalson) commented)

You want to have all your data as an associative array.

In order to do that, in the example you posted, `json1` must be passed thru `json_decode`.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $row['json1'] = json_decode( $row['json1'], true ); // <----
        $resultArray[] = $row;
}
return $resultArray;
```

Now you should get the desired result:

```
echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Building the desired structure with MySQL can be done like this:

```
mysql> SELECT JSON_OBJECT('id', 1, 'json1', JSON_OBJECT('key1', 1, 'key2', 'abc')) AS obj;
+------------------------------------------------+
| obj                                            |
+------------------------------------------------+
| {"id": 1, "json1": {"key1": 1, "key2": "abc"}} |
+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And in PHP, we can either go from JSON to array:

```
php > var_dump(json_decode('{"id":1,"json1":{"key1":1,"key2":"abc"}}', TRUE));
array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["json1"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["key1"]=>
    int(1)
    ["key2"]=>
    string(3) "abc"
  }
}
```

Or array to JSON:

```
php > $tmp = ['id' => 1, 'json1' => ['key1' => 1, 'key2' => 'abc']];
php > var_dump($tmp);
array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["json1"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["key1"]=>
    int(1)
    ["key2"]=>
    string(3) "abc"
  }
}
php > print(json_encode($tmp));
{"id":1,"json1":{"key1":1,"key2":"abc"}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, your suggestion doesn't seem to work - this is what I get:
[
{
obj: "{"id": 1, "json1": {"key1": 1, "key2": "abc"}}"
}
]

Comment: As you can see, I copied and pasted directly from command-line PHP and MySQL.

What are your needs that are not yet met?

Comment: What are you running, and what are the desired results?

Comment: Well, there is just one long string in the JSON - "{"id": 1, "json1": {"key1": 1, "key2": "abc"}}". I'm running PHP 7.0.25 and MySQL 5.7.20.

Comment: What would you like to do with this JSON?

Comment: You're currently putting in in an object as a string. If you use json_decode to make it into an object, then you can put it in as a key and re-encode the whole thing. If you supply your code I can show you how this would look

Comment: mysqli will not cast a `JSON_OBJECT` to a php array or stdObject. you need to call `json_decode` in your loop if you want to re-encode for output.