# I want a more consolidate json format

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am getting json array after getting applying query logic.

```
[
    {
        "id": "3",
        "diag_name": "LT Diagnostics",
        "test_name": "Alk PO4",
        "booking_date": "2018-05-20"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "diag_name": "LT Diagnostics",
        "test_name": "CRP",
        "booking_date": "2018-05-20"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "diag_name": "Seepz Diagnostics",
        "test_name": "Alk PO4",
        "booking_date": "2018-05-21"
    }
]
```

But i want a more justified json array written below.

```
[
    {
        "diag_name": "LT Diagnostics",
        "test_name": [
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name" : "Alk PO4"
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name" : "CRP"
            }
        ],
        "booking_date": "2018-05-20"
    },
     {
        "diag_name": "Seepz Diagnostics",
        "test_name": [
            {
                "id": "4",
                "name" : "Alk PO4"
            }
        ],
        "booking_date": "2018-05-21"
    },

]
```

I am not getting it,How to  do in php.  I want a more consolidate json format.

Comment: you are getting this JSON in server side or front-end?

Comment: Probably, you have to write a method to get to this format... have a try at it, that should not be too hard after all. If you are stuck, edit your question, attach the code you already wrote and we'll have a look at it

Comment: server side-PHP from sql query @ShrihariBalasubramani

Comment: @NicoHaase plz help me what kind of method i have to write.

Comment: Personally, I think JSON arrays of key/value pairs are fantastic. PHP encodes it right out of the box into a format a simply jquery for each loop can parse right out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your SQL query to group by diag_name and booking_date? That would be the first step I’d employ to get the outer data.

Formatting the data in the nested manner you’re after could be a function of whatever record serializer you’re using — does it support nested JSON as a return type, or only flat JSON as your example return value shows?

If the record set -> JSON serializer only ever returns flat data, the comments above are correct that you will have to write your own formatter to change the shape of the JSON yourself...

The accepted answer of this other question may be of help:

[Create multi-level JSON with PHP and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996806/create-multi-level-json-with-php-and-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP guy but this is a typical scenario to use functional programming by means of the monad Map.

Looking online I've found [this article](http://eddmann.com/posts/mapping-filtering-and-reducing-in-php/) that could help you.

Changing datasource output is not always (seldom indeed) a viable option.

Enjoy coding