# How to remove double quotes from a sql query using with php?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to build a json object directly from sql php and mysql but I'm having problems with double quote characters.

```
<?php
include_once '../src/conexao.php';

$exercicio_id = $_POST['id'];


$sql = $pdo->query("SELECT text,JSON_ARRAY(GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT(\"instruction\", 
       ei.instruction))) as 
       instructions,JSON_OBJECT(\"link\",link,\"start_at\",start_at,\"end_at\",end_at) as video 
       FROM exercises as e LEFT JOIN exercises_videos as ev ON e.exercise_video_id = ev.id CROSS 
       JOIN exercises_informations_bodies as eib
       ON e.exercise_information_id = eib.id CROSS JOIN exercises_instructions as ei
       ON eib.id = ei.exercise_information_id WHERE e.id = ".$exercicio_id."")- 
       >fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($sql);

?>
```

Returns json:

```
[{  "text":"Supino \u00e9 um exerc\u00edcio multiarticulares, ou seja, que envolve v\u00e1rias articula\u00e7\u00f5es, que tem como \u00eanfase o trabalho do m\u00fasculo peitoral maior.",
    "instructions":"[
            \"{\\\"instruction\\\": \\\"Os p\u00e9s devem estar bem fixados no ch\u00e3o\\\"},
            {\\\"instruction\\\": \\\"Os punhos devem estar alinhados com os cotovelos e linha m\u00e9dia do peitoral.\\\"},
            {\\\"instruction\\\": \\\"As costas devem estar contra\u00eddas no momento da execu\u00e7\u00e3o do supino, 
            mantendo o arco natural da lombar atrav\u00e9s da aproxima\u00e7\u00e3o das esc\u00e1pulas.
            Isso dar\u00e1 mais estabilidade durante o movimento, permitindo maiores cargas.\\\"}
            \"]",
    "video":"{\"link\": \"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=F-VRl1NEtvs\", \"start_at\": 0, \"end_at\": 60}"
}]
```

In some curly braces and square brackets, I have double quotes which make the json wrong. Already tried using JSON_UNQUOT, JSON_EXTRACT.

I even used `str_replace`, I was able to remove the double quotes with this method, but the quotes went to the start and end of the JSON.

Comment: This seems related, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996806/create-multi-level-json-with-php-and-mysql